# Change the time stamp on comments to "time last edited"

Tags: feature-request, comments, timestamps

I would like to see the time that comments were last edited, rather than the time they were initially posted.

All too often I see comment threads which don't make any sense, but which would if I knew which order they were edited in!

And since the system already updates the comments themselves in the database, and adds the "was edited" flags, it wouldn't be too expensive to change the datetimes to "now" too.

Comment: Since you can only edit comments for 5 minutes, how often does this really happen?

Comment: @psubsee2003 All too.

Comment: This will be too confusing/misleading in my opinion. I would rather prefer to have the pencil tooltip show the time of last edit - enough for those who want to know.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure, that would be one solution. Why don't you post that as an answer? Still, a disadvantage of implementing it like that would be that the system would need to store two timestamps in the database (the original and the edited time).

Comment: Will try posting with some more details tomorrow, but one thing is sure, they will never remove the date in which the comment was originally posted, if anything they'll add another field, if such field doesn't exist already.

Comment: Hm, you mean because the original time is needed for the 5 minute editing limit. I hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good feature in some occasions.

First, you have a five minute grace period to edit your comment until the time is up. When actively commenting and replying, comments might pop up after yours and sometimes, within 5 minutes. If the time changes, the comments seem to not to be in order. With posts, it says when it was edited, but still keep the original posting time.

Second, why do we need to know it was edited anyways? There is no way to see the revision history so it is kinda useless to know when it was edited. To see when it was edited, the users should know what was before the newest edit. You cannot if you imply this unless they make a new feature...

Comment: The problem with editing is that the comment I'm looking at now is the comment as the author actually intended, not as it was originally (badly) written. So why show the time when it was originally written, rather than the time it was written to be as it is now? Not to mention that comments can be (and some _are_) changed completely, leaving no trace of what they were originally, but still bearing the original timestamp.